# Is there a way to edit last search/substitution pattern in vi?

Tags: vi, replace

I made a mistake in a complex search pattern in vi editor and want to modify it now.

I know vi remembers the last search pattern but can I view and edit it ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Modern vi/vim keeps a history of `:` and `/` command used in vi. So you can just press up arrow key to get your search pattern again and then edit it.

Comment: Brilliant. Works like a charm.